# Rails Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm integrating a theme from wrapbootstrap.com and I just realized i'm running into an issue.

scripts.js that's included with the theme is conflicting with the two files I'm including in application.js

`//= require jquery`

`//= require jquery_ujs`

I know this because my `logout` functionality stopped working which has a route as:

```
delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", "/logout" , :method => "delete" %>
```

I suppose my question is how can I include both `scripts.js` along with the rails required classes? **If I remove `scripts.js` the logout functionality returns and when I require it again the functionality goes away.**

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to just make it a `GET` request rather than have a `DELETE` `HTTP` request in my `routes.rb` files.